# How to work with multiple project folders in Vim?

Tags: vim-windows, netrw, plugin-ctrlp

I am often working with multiple projects at the same time. For example one main project and 5 related librairies. I have some issue to properly search in one project or multiple. I would like to:

- Be able to search with CtrlP only in current git repo when I have a file open or in multiple git repo
- Easily view multiple selected repositories in netrw or similar

Thanks

Comment: Too broad question(s) I think. And "best" is quite subjective.

Comment: You are correct. I tried a new version

Comment: Maybe not the solution you'd like to hear, but how about having one vim open per library? And have tags specific to each one of those? You could also have one window opened which is global (has access to all your files).

Comment: That's not a bad idea. But a little more gymnastic for window management

Answer (score 1):

Use vim-ctrlspace. It allows managing workspaces(saving and restoring full state of vim) and loading tabs (tab workspaces ). 
Handle tab for each project, and 
use `lcd`  to get different folders for different tabs, and have ctrlp look in the current directory (there is a command `:CtrlPCurWD`).

I also suggest my changes to vim-ctrlspace https://github.com/eyalk5/vim-ctrlspace that allows managing all workspaces in single file, independently of the working folder. But it doesn't handle well `lcd` (need to fix). So either fix that or work with the original.

Comment: with tabs better use tcd